# JSON deserializer with generic type using TypeReference

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to generalise this method:

```
public EventStream<Greeting> deserialize(String value){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    EventStream<Greeting> data = null;
    try {
        data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, new TypeReference<EventStream<Greeting>>() {});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

where EventStream is:

```
public class EventStream<T> {

    private EventHeaders headers;

    @JsonDeserialize
    private T payload;
}
```

What I'd like to have is replace the specific Object Greeting with a generic, in the deserialize method.

I tried with this:

```
public <T> EventStream<T> deserialize(String value){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    EventStream<T> data = null;
    try {
        data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, new TypeReference<EventStream<T>>() {});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

But the payload inside the EventStream result is deserialized as LinkedHashMap. It seems like TypeReference ignored the generic type.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: If it were possible to reflect on a generic type, TypeReference wouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you encountered here is a common problem caused by something called type erasure, the way java implements generics.

> Type erasure can be explained as the process of enforcing type
>   constraints only at compile time and discarding the element type
>   information at runtime. [1]

So at the time you try to deserialize your object, the type T is not known and it is just treated as `Object` and the deserialization result will default default to `Map` (`LinkedHashMap` to be precise).

You could make your method generic by passing your targetClass as an additional argument to the function call like so:

```
public <T> EventStream<T> deserialize(String value, Class<T> targetClass)
```

Then you use the TypeFactory of your mapper to create a type of this targetClass

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(EventStream.class, targetClass);
```

which you can pass to the readValue method:

```
data = mapper.readValue(value, type);
```

Complete code:

```
public <T> EventStream<T> deserialize(String value, Class<T> targetClass){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory()
        .constructParametricType(EventStream.class, targetClass);
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(value, type);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

[1] https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

Comment: I got your point on Type erasure, but your solution what should be the targetClass input parameter?
I mean, if I call this:
`EventStream<Greeting> data = deserialize(value, Greeting.class);`
It doesn't still work. I guess I need to pass information about EventStream and the generic type. So, I changed your solution with this:
`JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(EventStream.class, targetClass);`
And It seems to work. Do you see any cons here?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the class of T, so in your case thats `Greeting.class`. And you are right, you obviously need a `ParametricType` not just a `Type` - edited my answer.

Comment: I think this is a feasible solution though. The only con I see here is that you need kind of need to pass your class twice, first as a generic argmuent `T` and then as the actual class `targetClass`, which feels a bit awkward IMO. However, I can't think of a better solution to achieve what you want to do.